# NamedQuery join and filter collection

Tags: java, jpql, named-query

I've tried to do this query but it still selects every child even though I just want the ones with the specific name. How would I achieve that?

```
@NamedQuery(name="Parent.getChildrenWithName",
                query="SELECT p FROM Parent p "
                        + "join p.children c "
                        + "where c.name = :childName")
public class Parent
{
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "parentId")
    private List<Child> children;
}

public class Child
{
    @Column(name = "ChildName")
    private String childName;

    private int parentId;
}
```

Just read this on http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtl.html#bnbtr:

*Expressions cannot navigate beyond (or further qualify) relationship fields that are collections. In the syntax of an expression, a collection-valued field is a terminal symbol. Because the teams field is a collection, the WHERE clause cannot specify p.teams.city (an illegal expression).*

This is my code that fetches the result:

```
TypedQuery<Parent> query = em.createNamedQuery("Parent.getChildrenWithName", Parent.class);
query.setParameter("childName", "Daniel");
Parent parent = query.getSingleResult();
```

But the question remains :)

Comment: You have a named query 'Parent.getChildrenWithName' which other part of your code are your using it. Can you paste the code which refers this named query ?

Comment: edited my question with that code!

Comment: You query on Child.name (`... where c.name = :childName`) but your entity has mapped column `ChildName` to `persnr`. Perhaps you should query with `c.persnr` instead. Maybe you have a property `name` on the class and you actually query against it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like below,

```
    TypedQuery<Parent> query = em.createNamedQuery("Parent.getChildrenWithName", Parent.class);
    query.setParameter("childName", "Daniel");
    Parent parent = query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm doing (Except there is only one parent) but it still fetches all children for my parent, not only Daniel.

Comment: What is the difference? :)

Comment: When you first posted if was a different name, I think you have edited now.

Comment: Yeah sorry, noticed and changed that.